# Reducer task is not being invoked in my MapReduce job

Tags: scala, hadoop, mapreduce

It's a word-count map reduce job. I have my own InputFormat.

JobExecutor:

```
val job = new Job(new Configuration())

job.setMapperClass(classOf[CountMapper])
job.setReducerClass(classOf[CountReducer])

job.setJobName("tarun-test-1")
job.setInputFormatClass(classOf[MyInputFormat])
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args(0)))
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args(1)))

job.setOutputKeyClass(classOf[Text])
job.setOutputValueClass(classOf[LongWritable])

job.setNumReduceTasks(1)

println("status: " + job.waitForCompletion(true))
```

Mapper:

```
class CountMapper extends Mapper[LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable] {

    private val valueOut = new LongWritable(1L)

    override def map(k: LongWritable, v: Text, context: Mapper[LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable]#Context): Unit = {
        val str = v.toString
        str.split(",").foreach(word => {
            val keyOut = new Text(word.toLowerCase.trim)
            context.write(keyOut, valueOut)
        })
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
class CountReducer extends Reducer[Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable] {

    override def reduce(k: Text, values: Iterable[LongWritable], context: Reducer[Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable]#Context): Unit = {
        println("Inside reduce method..")
        val valItr = values.iterator()
        var sum = 0L
        while (valItr.hasNext) {
            sum = sum + valItr.next().get()
        }

        context.write(k, new LongWritable(sum))
        println("done reducing.")
    }
}
```

Mapper is being invoked and RecordReader is reading splits properly based on the logs. However, reducer is not being invoked.

Comment: what do you mean you have your own InputFormat? Where is it? And what do you mean reducing is not being invoked? How do you know that? Any input/output? Counters? Errors? Logs?

Comment: MyInputFormat is my own InputFormat. InputFormat is working as expected, i see that mapper's input (key, value) are being read by RecordReader correctly. I added logging to Map task and it is logging things as expected. However, reduce logs are not printed and final status is false.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting :
job.mapOutputKeyClass and job.MapOutputValueClass .

Comment: MapOutputKeyClass and MapOutputValueClass aren't mandatory if OutputKeyClass and OutputValueClass are the same.